# Translate AppleScript to Python appscript (`do javascript`)

Tags: python, applescript, py-appscript, sourceforge-appscript

This is the AppleScript template:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
  set theFile to alias “Application:Documents:MyFile” open theFile
  do javascript (file <path to Emboss.jsx>) with arguments { 75,2,89 }
end tell
```

And I would like to translate that to Python appscript. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to translate the `do javascript`. Any ideas?

I don't even know how to find it out. Maybe I know AppleScript too less. Is `do` a keyword? Or is it a command I am sending to the application? Is `javascript` a parameter of `do`? Or does `do javascript` belong together (as a command with a space)?

Comment: `do javascript` is probably a command to run Js code (in this case the code is in a file). You normally use this in Safari, but adobe apps also support this

Comment: Why the close vote without even giving any comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To translate generic `AppleScript` to `appscript`, use the `ASTranslate` tool available from the  `appscript` web site [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/tools.html).  It is not always able to successfully translate due to the quirks and bugs in the script definitions of some applications but it is a good place to start.

Comment: Cool! It seems that `do javascript` indeed translates canonically to `do_javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't exactly know how to translate the above (and more generally: I don't know how to translate any generic AppleScript code to Python appscript).

However, for the above case, I found that there is the command `do_javascript`. It doesn't seem to execute files though but rather executes the given JS code string directly.

E.g., this works:

```
from appscript import *
import os, sys

ps = app("Adobe Photoshop CS5")

filelist = sys.argv[1:]

jsCode = """
var g_StackScriptFolderPath = app.path + "/Presets/Scripts/" 
var runMergeToHDRFromScript = true; 
$.evalFile(g_StackScriptFolderPath + "Merge to HDR.jsx");
mergeToHDR.mergeFilesToHDR(%s, true);
""" % (repr(filelist),)

ps.do_javascript(jsCode)
```